# Autowired constructor not instantiating dependencies properly in Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an integration which instantiates a service and that service has an `Autowired` dependency on a bean I'm trying to mock.

The problem is the service is getting instantiated before the autowired bean is and causing NPE. How can I ensure `DependencyINeed` is initialized before the `MyClass` in the example below?

## Service

```java
@Service
public class MyClass {
  @Autowired private DependencyINeed dependency;

  @Autowired
  public MyClass(
      @Value("${thing1}") int t1,
      @Value("${thing2}") String t2) {

      }
```

#### Method call yielding NPE

```
public class MyClass {
....

   public void randomFunction() {
        dependency.methodCall() <-- NPE
   }

}
```

## Test

```java
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfiguration.class)
@Import({TestConfiguration.class})
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = {TestConfiguration.class, DependencyINeed.class, MyClass.class})
public class MyCoolIntegrationTest {

  @Autowired private DependencyINeed dependency;

  @Autowired private MyClass client;
```

## Test Configuration

```
@TestConfiguration
public class MyTestConfiguration {

  @MockBean private DependencyINeed dep;

  @Bean
  public DependencyINeed initDep() {
     ....
    return dep;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your DependencyINeed is a comnponent or service? (@Component/@Service). And delete your test config and use @Mockbean in your test.

Comment: DependencyINeed is just an external library (not component or service) and the reason I have the initDep function is because I add some mock calls into it when methods are executed against the mockbean

Comment: Can you share the code where the NPE is happening?

Comment: The NPE is happening on a method that exists on DependencyINeed because DependencyINeed is null

Comment: Yes, but _where_, please post the full code and the stacktrace optionally.

Comment: @GaëlJ added code to show how it's causing NPE

Comment: If there is an issue in the constructor, dependency calls a method in the constructor as well, but if the mocks haven't been initialized, I will yield an NPE

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete yout test config, and make yout Test class look like this:

```html
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfiguration.class)
@Import({TestConfiguration.class})
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = {TestConfiguration.class, DependencyINeed.class, MyClass.class})
public class MyCoolIntegrationTest {

  @MockBean private DependencyINeed dependency;

  @Autowired private MyClass client;
 
    @BeforeEach
    public void beforeEach() {
        Mockito.when(dependency.SOMEHING()).thenReturn(YOUR STUFF);
    }

 
 }
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the DependencyINeed is null when MyClass is initialized.

Comment: If there is an issue in the constructor, dependency calls a method, but if the mocks haven't been initialized, I will yield an NPE